# How can an old Apple ID be merged into the newer ID?

Tags: itunes

When I first creed an Apple account, years ago, I used a password which I've been using ever since. Later I joined *Me.com* and I was assigned an email address that also became another Apple ID for me. More recently, with the new iCloud it looks like only my email address will be accepted as the ID t... So, how do I merge my now "old" ID into my newer @me.com address? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As of now, you cannot merge multiple Apple IDs into one Apple ID. It has been rumored but it is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Apple still working on it. I know about it from last news.

http://www.macrumors.com/2011/10/18/apple-still-working-on-allowing-merging-of-apple-ids/

Comment: You could link to the news to improve this answer.

Comment: http://www.macrumors.com/2011/10/18/apple-still-working-on-allowing-merging-of-apple-ids/

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is a rumour, therefore you cannot "know". Apple is _supposedly_ working on it.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an idea.  What you can do, if you haven't bought much or anything on your new ID.  You can change the email address on your apple ID once every 90 days (which is important, make sure you do this right the first time).

So change your me.com address to something else entirely.  Make a new temporary email on gmail if you have to.  Then change your old apple ID to your current me.com address.  And all your old purchases are now under your brand spanking new email address.

Comment: The Apple ID never changes. You can add an alternate email should you want one Apple ID to send mails to another address, but the infrastructure to either re-sign purchases, forward mails from old Apple ID that are mac.com/me.com as well as how to handle other merging of two accounts is not engineering work Apple has released to the public.